# What happens with enol and ketone

Tags: acid-base

What process happens between an enol and a ketone, so that the ketone will enolate and become acidic?

Please, explain what happens with them in this process?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because the enol and ketone aren't stable, **equilibrium** happens; therefore the enol has a chance of losing a hydrogen ion and because of that, the enol becomes an enolate.

Also keep in mind that an acid is a molecule that can donate a proton.
The enolate is a base and it's gathering/accepting a proton from the hydrogen.

I assume this is what you meant when you asked the question.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. There was a similar question to this before, so next time before you ask something, remember to see if a similar question to it has already been answered.

Comment: "Enol and Ketone aren't stable, the process called Equilibrium happens"  - you should be more careful with reasoning. 1) What would it even mean they aren't stable? 2) Equilibrium isn't a process.

Comment: @Mithoron I am aware that it isn't a process, I used that word on accident. Was going to edit my post but it got accepted, so I thought it wasn't needed. Thanks though.

Comment: I really don't get what you are trying to say with your first paragraph. Equilibrium is not a type of chemical reaction... Furthermore the deprotonation can occur directly from the ketone and tautomerisation to the enol form isn't required for deprotonation